# mysql связанная таблица недоступна если в ней более 99 записей. Почему?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE `table_id` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `tab_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `forecasts_tab_id_foreign` (`tab_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `forecasts_tab_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`tab_id`) REFERENCES `table_id` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

[image: от 1 до 99 записей]

[image: от 100 и более записей]

Comment: Что значит `недоступна`?

Comment: Если в table_id добавить 100-ую запись, то table по колонке tab_id пропадает возможность выбора информации из table_id

Comment: Где пропадает возможность выбора?

Comment: Добавил изображения. Возможно так будет яснее.

Comment: Потому, что так работает phpmyadmin. К MySQL это никакого отношения не имеет

Comment: Настройте клиента, уберите это ограничение.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь